# Wildfly 10 Standalone deployment

Tags: java

I have deployed the unzipped ear to standalone/deployments folder in wildfly 10,
i am getting implementation class not defined in interface while deploying.I am getting Noclassdefinition found exception.I could not figure out the problem...

Comment: Can you paste the stacktraces?

Comment: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."MegaDataOnlineEJB.jar".POST_M
ODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MegaDataOnlineEJB.jar".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODU
LE of deployment "MegaDataOnlineEJB.jar"
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/allianz/megadataonline/server/ejb/TransCheckNewboc (Module "deployment.MegaDataOnlineEJB.jar:main"
 from Service Module Loader): com/allianz/megadataonline/shared/ejb/TransCheckbocRemoteInterface

Comment: can anyone help me in solving this,i am extracting the .ear and deploying it in wildfly standalone deployments folder, i am getting noclassdefinition found because .class files are not referred i think so...

Comment: i have deployed the same ear in wildfly console and i could run the testclasses from eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

i think you should configure the environement variable to PATH by adding the bin path which is :
`C:\Program Files\wildfly-21.0.1.Final\bin`